# Next JS production routes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am getting started with NextJS and I have ran into this issue that I don't see with react and Node/ Express. NextJS has built in api routing example: http://localhost:3000/api/test (next will only accept absolute urls)

Here is my code in development:

```
const Recipes = ({recipes}) => {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Recipes</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
          {recipes.map((recipe)=> {
            return <p>{recipe.title.rendered}</p>
          })}
     
      </main>
    </div>
  )
}

// This function gets called at build time on server-side.
// It won't be called on client-side, so you can even do
// direct database queries. See the "Technical details" section.

export async function getStaticProps() {

  const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';
  const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000' : 'https://example.com/';

  console.log("SERVER: ", server);

  const res = await fetch(`${server}/api/recipes')
  const recipes = await res.json();

  return {
    props: {
      recipes,
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  }
}

export default About;
```

This works fine in dev.
So when I run *npm run build* or try to deploy to Vercel (vercel creats a production build) I get an error

**Error: Export encountered errors on following paths:
/recipes
[    ] info  - Generating static pages (0/3)npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE**

How can I set this up so my dev and prodbuilds work. How am I supposed to have and api endpoint on my server if build always fails.

I understand that next compiles everytime I save but the api is available on localhost. It is not available at http://example.com because I can't build with the api being called. I am able to build with dev running in another terminal but then build fails in production.

I have found very little info about this issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: In short, you can't. Why? The server isn't running when the build is compiling. Therefore, any attempts to connect to the API within gSProps or gSPaths will fail. Click [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/12229#discussioncomment-93027) for an explanation of the limitations and a work-around (while it focuses on a database connection and queries, the same concept holds true for API requests).

Comment: On that note, I don't think Vercel allows locally hosted databases nor custom Express servers. You'll have to go with a [VPS](https://www.vpsbenchmarks.com/best_vps).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is a little disappointing. I usually use a separate process for the node api but I liked the simplicity of next built in api routes. Why do they exist. I don’t see any way to use it at all. There must be some way to make it work.

Comment: They exist for client-side requests and/or server-side requests using `getServerSideProps`.

Comment: I found this on the NextJS repo. I cloned it and deployed to vercel and their example worked perfectly. - [working example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/api-routes)
I am able to deploy & build using swr library but once up on vercel the api route doesn't exist and the call fails with a 404 even though their example worked. I compared to my app and I can't see a difference. Is there some config option I'm missing.

Comment: Thanks Matt. I actually just read that. I will definitely try using serverSideProps but I will eventually need a more realtime update for my data. I'm now looking into incremental static regeneration.

Comment: Using `SWR` means client-side only requests (no iSSG). Also, that example doesn't use a database nor a custom express server, it uses static predefined [data](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/api-routes/data.js) within Next's provided API routes.

Comment: Yeah but it's the request to the built in api route that isn't working. It doesn't matter what I do on the server side. Their example calls /api/people and gets a response. that is all I want to happen. I tried it their way and making a request with axios. They both don't work on Vercel. The route is just not there. But is fine in their example. Makes me think it's a project config or something.

Comment: Custom projects work as [expected](https://project-example.vercel.app/). You just need to make sure you're using the correct [baseUrl](https://github.com/mattcarlotta/project-example-vercel/blob/master/.env.production#L1) to the API for production.